# How can i prevent android camera intent from saving captured image twice?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera-intent

I'm working on a project which take photo from user then do some `image processing`.
and I'm using this code to capture user photo:

```
private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
private Uri imageUri;

public void takePhoto(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/glasses/",  "temp.png");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

and it works correctly but the problem is the photo has been saved twice in two different directories:

> 1. /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera
> 2. /storage/emulated/0/glasses

How can I prevent camera intent from saving the captured image to camera base directory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that because you are saving the picture in your code.

Comment: @MuhammadTufail yes i'm saving the image to do some image processing and i want to save in one directory !!

Comment: One directory mean which directory ?

Comment: in /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera the picture is save by camera and in /storage/emulated/0/glasses directory you are saving image as temp.png

Comment: @Champandorid ofcourse the directory i have created `/storage/emulated/0/glasses`

Comment: you can delete all the files of your folder

Comment: you need to delete the picture from the other directory. if you want to save  in one directory like in your case you want to save picture only in /storage/emulated/0/glasses directory

Comment: @MuhammadTufail but how it saved from first to delete it , is that something default with opening camera to take a photo

Comment: in which directory you want to save picture..

Comment: @MuhammadTufail glasses dir

Comment: there are two way of doing this
1) Delete the picture the first location like Gallery
2) change the image path

Comment: the image saved in the DCIM folder is by default if you want to don't show in the gallery then you can do it and if you want to delete that image from DCIM then you can also do it.

Comment: @MuhammadTufail yes i want to delete it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156241/discussion-between-muhammad-tufail-and-stack-user).

Answer (score 0):

There is one option you have to delete last taken picture from the default location :

I think this may be help you:-

```
  private void deleteLastPhotoFromGallery() {

        String[] projection = new String[] {
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE };

        final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, 
                                null,null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + "  
                                DESC");

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int column_index_data =  
                        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

                         String image_path = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

            File file = new File(image_path);
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Champandorid for answer , great idea but two issues 
1- the file not deleted 
2- why it saved from first to gallery if i saved it on glasses dir

Comment: Just because of firstly camera save that image to the default directory and then your custom directory .

Comment: okay thanks but when i tried your code it seem the image is deleted but not deleted it shows black photo instead

Comment: Which device you are using?

Comment: i'm using lenovo tablet

Comment: It could be device Issue , It will work fine . But according to me your half problem is solved .

Comment: I will try it on another device or genymotion but it removes glasses folder image correctly with my code `try {
                    file.getCanonicalFile().delete();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }`

Comment: Deleting what camera saves is very counterproductive. More than that, it is not a device issue, it is how camera app must operate - it returns a thumbnail in imageUri and saves the large image in Camera filder. Instead, the camera should be commanded not to save the image by itself, but to return the full-size image in the supplied Uri. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for deleting lastest image from the DCIM folder

```
private void deleteLatest() {
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera");

    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator < Object > () {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

            if (((File) o1).lastModified() > ((File) o2).lastModified()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (((File) o1).lastModified() < ((File) o2).lastModified()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

    });
    files[0].delete();

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but the same as @Champandorid make new black image

Answer (score 0):

You should not delete anything. This is counterproductive.

Your code now does the following:
- you supply the camera app with the Uri to which the camera app saves a small copy of the image, while saving the large copy to the Camera folder itself.

You need to change your code so that the Camera app saves to your Uri the full-size image without saving the image itself.

This is done by:

```
intent.setClipData(imageUri);

intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_URI_READ_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_URI_WRITE_PERMISDION);
```

And don't use:

```
intent.putExtra(...)
```

There may be another problem you may face if you use Android 6.0 or newer: the camera app will throw SecurityException trying to write image to your imageUri. In that case you need to use FileProvider

Comment: @GilbertoIbarra it took you 6 years. nice to have you back

Comment: Wrong post, haha

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to guarantee *anything* when you invoke **ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE**. I mean, you cannot know which application will get started, and it may be not 100% compliant, or buggy, or do something on purpose.

The users are free to use the camera app that is preinstalled on their device (and most ODMs choose to supply their custom apps), or download another camera app from Play Store or sideload it. Even if the app complies with all the specs, it has full right to store the captured files in any location, or multiple locations, on the device - this depends only on the system permissions the app has.

The bottom line is, [your deleted answer to yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47428233/192373) is correct. It is worthwhile to bundle your custom camera implementation if you want better control of device camera(s). You can rely on open source libraries (e.g. https://android-arsenal.com/tag/141) to get started.